# GEE Hypothesis Test for Regression Slope

Tags: google-earth-engine, regression

I am using Google Earth Engine to calculate linear trends over time using the linearFit reducer. I am interested in identifying pixels that exhibit significant increasing and decreasing trends using a standard hypothesis test on the slope parameter. This is what I have so far:

```
var point = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([-133.49, 69.18]);
var l5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',10))
  .select(['B3', 'B4'])
  .filterBounds(point)
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(7,8,'month'));

//adds ndvi as band 'B4_1'
var ndvi = function(image) {
  var nir = image.select('B4');
  var red = image.select('B3');
  var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red));
  var proimage = image.addBands(ndvi);
  return proimage;
};

var createTimeBand = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start').divide(3.154e10));
};
var stack = l5.map(ndvi).map(createTimeBand);
var linearFit = stack.select(['system:time_start','B4_1'])
.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit());

// Reproject using the CRS parameters of one of the original images.
var reprojected = linearFit.reproject({
  crs:'EPSG:32609', 
  crsTransform:[30,0,278985,0,-30,7849515], 
});
var linpar = {min: 0, max: [-0.01, 0.01, 5], bands: ['scale', 'scale', 'offset']};
Map.addLayer(reprojected, linpar, 'reprojected');
Map.setCenter(-133.50, 69.19, 9);
```

The linearFit reducer returns the slope and offset, but I am wondering if there is some way to retrieve the standard error or p-values for these parameters. Are there other earth engine functions that would allow me to calculate confidence intervals or p-values?